# Why does $.ajax load the [base url + index.html] repetitively when requested relative url is not found

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a situation where I load a file and move the content of that file to a placeholder in the HTML. The idea is visible in the code below which is the smallest snippet I could think of which mimics the issue.

When executing while the file in the webroot exists, there is no problem.

When executing while the file is non-existent, the webroot index.html starts loading repetitively while I just want it to execute the fail(). It should load nothing. The effect can be reproduced both in FF and in Chrome.

I must be missing something obvious. I used several ajax options (cache, timeout, headers, Crossdomain ), without effect.

My questions are : what causes this effect? 
What am I doing wrong (again: I just want it to execute the fail() )? 
What can I do to prevent this?

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            Promise.all([LoadCUsermenu('CUsermenu.txt')]).then( ()=>{console.log('Promise fullfilled')} );
            console.log('Do the rest of the stuff')
        });

        function LoadCUsermenu(filename) {
            return $.ajax({
                url: filename
            }).done(function (response, responseStatus) {
                console.log('Usermenu present...Loading');
                $('#CUsermenu').html(response)
            }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('No Usermenu present...' + textStatus);
                $('#CUsermenu').html("<li>Nothing there</li>")
            })
        }
    </script>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id='CUsermenu'></ul>
    <div><p>Wil this be loaded repetetively???</p></div>
</body>
```

Comment: maybe your webserver redirecting the 404 to index file

Comment: I tried that by loading the file directly in the browser and indeed it loads the index.html. Would that mean I would need to catch all possible errors to prevent this from happening? How can I block this (this is not only for my server but for everywhere this application runs).

Comment: I would configure the server not to redirect 404 to the index page, at least for Ajax requests.

Comment: And apart from the above, the ajax call comes back with a 'succes' and the index.html in the response. While clearly the requested file does not exist.

Comment: Not only for the 404, or the 301 but for any error code indicating error. As said: I may do that for my own server but not for the server of other users. So how to handle that?

Comment: Problem solved: the htaccess contained an erroneous "RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]" which should not be there. No doubt my own bad.

Thanks for the questions which guided my search towards the solution.